# How to make template for Rails paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my application, I added several routes for specific actions to various objects:

```
  resources :business_rules do
      resources :breaches
      member do
        post :new_version
        post :make_current
        post :finalise
        post :activate
      end
      collection do
        get :index_all
      end
  end
```

Which I reach thanks to a button:

```
<%= button_to t('MakeCurrent'), make_current_business_rule_path(@business_rule.id), class: "buttons mid_menu" %>
```

This is used repeatedly for 12 objects, and 4 buttons, so I wish to insert this action bar in a partial and invoke it in each of the 12 show views, respectively for each targeted object. But how can I generate the make_current_*targeted_object*_path ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [polymorpic route helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.7/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html#method-i-polymorphic_path) in Rails instead of the named route helpers.

In fact you have already used them if you ever have done `link_to 'Show', @thing` or `form_for @thing`.

```
 link_to("Text", [:make_current, @object], method: :post)
 # or
 button_to("Text", [:make_current, @object], method: :post)
```

See [Creating Paths and URLs From Objects](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a helper method to your application_controller:

```
helper_method :generate_path

def generate_path(action, target):
    send [action, target, 'path'].join('_')
end
```

And use it like this:

```
<%= button_to t('MakeCurrent'), generate_path('make_current', 'buisness_rule'), class: "buttons mid_menu" %>
```

Comment: Creative, but pretty redundant. The named route helpers are merely a developer convenience and actually map to the polymorphic route helpers. This just adds an additional level of complexity. It also does not  deal with the fact that you need to send arguments to the path helpers...